# How do I handle ruby arrays in ruby ffi gem?

Tags: c, ruby, ffi

I want to use the ruby ffi gem to call a c function which has an array as an input variable and the output is an array. That is, the c function looks like:

```
double *my_function(double array[], int size)
```

I have created the ruby binding as:

```
module MyModule
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'c'
  ffi_lib 'my_c_lib'
  attach_function :my_function, [:pointer, int], :pointer
```

I will like to make a call in ruby code like:

```
result_array = MyModule.my_function([4, 6, 4], 3)
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 9):

Let's say that this is the library you wish to use in your ruby script, call it `my_c_lib.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

double *my_function(double array[], int size)
{
  int i = 0;
  double *new_array = malloc(sizeof(double) * size);
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    new_array[i] = array[i] * 2;
  }

  return new_array;
}
```

You can compile it like so:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c my_c_lib.c -o my_c_lib.o
$ gcc -shared -o my_c_lib.so my_c_lib.o
```

Now, it's ready to use in in your ruby code (`my_c_lib.rb`):

```
require 'ffi'

module MyModule
  extend FFI::Library

  # Assuming the library files are in the same directory as this script
  ffi_lib "./my_c_lib.so"

  attach_function :my_function, [:pointer, :int], :pointer
end

array = [4, 6, 4]
size = array.size
offset = 0

# Create the pointer to the array
pointer = FFI::MemoryPointer.new :double, size

# Fill the memory location with your data
pointer.put_array_of_double offset, array

# Call the function ... it returns an FFI::Pointer
result_pointer = MyModule.my_function(pointer, size)

# Get the array and put it in `result_array` for use
result_array = result_pointer.read_array_of_double(size)

# Print it out!
p result_array
```

And here is the result of running the script:

```
$ ruby my_c_lib.rb
[8.0, 12.0, 8.0]
```

A note on memory management...from the docs https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Pointers:

> The FFI::MemoryPointer class allocates native memory with automatic garbage collection as a sweetener. When a MemoryPointer goes out of scope, the memory is freed up as part of the garbage collection process.

So you shouldn't have to call `pointer.free` directly. Also, just to check whether you had to manually free `result_pointer`, I called `result_pointer.free` after printing extracting the array and got this warning

```
warning: calling free on non allocated pointer #<FFI::Pointer address=0x007fd32b611ec0>
```

So it looks like you don't have to manually free `result_pointer` either.