# Array#push causes "stack level too deep" error with large arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I made two arrays, each with 1 million items:

```
a1 = 1_000_000.times.to_a
a2 = a1.clone
```

I tried to push a2 into a1:

```
a1.push *a2
```

This returns `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`.

However, when I try with `concat`, I don't get the error:

```
a1.concat a2
a1.length # => 2_000_000
```

I also don't get the error with the splat operator:

```
a3 = [*a1, *a2]
a3.length # => 2_000_000
```

Why is this the case? I looked at the documentation for [`Array#push`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-push), and it is written in C. I suspect that it may be doing some recursion under the hood, and that's why it's causing this error for large arrays. Is this correct? Is it not a good idea to use `push` for large arrays?

Comment: I don't have an exact answer, but in general I'd say that passing exceedingly large argument lists (where "exceedingly" is defined as upwards of a couple  hundred) tends to cause strange behavior, since argument lists are often stored somewhere in memory that makes assumptions about their size. Some languages even define a maximum argument count explicitly; for example, in Common Lisp the variable `CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT` tells you the maximum number of arguments.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think that this is not a recursion error, but an argument stack error. You are running up against the limit of the Ruby VM stack depth for arguments.

The problem is the splat operator, which is passed as an argument to `push`. The splat operator is expanded into a million element argument list for `push`.

As function arguments are passed as stack elements, and the pre-configured max size of the Ruby VM stack size is:

```
RubyVM::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:thread_vm_stack_size]
=> 1048576
```

..this is where the limit comes from.

You can try the following:

```
RUBY_THREAD_VM_STACK_SIZE=10000000 ruby array_script.rb
```

..and it will work fine.

This is also the reason you want to use `concat` instead, as the whole array can be passed as one single reference, and `concat` will then process the array internally. As opposed to `push` + splat, which will try to use the stack as a temporary storage for all the array elements.

Comment: But why does `[*a1]` work with default stack size? Is the call being optimized?

Comment: Because it's not a call, it's a literal. The argument list on the call stack doesn't overflow because there are no arguments, because there is no call.

Comment: @JörgWMittag that makes sense, somehow. I expected it to fail in the same way because – although no Ruby method is being called – the underlying C code to create and fill an array out of `a1`'s elements has to be invoked.

Comment: Yes, but probably with one argument, not with one million.

Answer (score 2):

Casper has already answered the question in the title and given you a solution you can use to make `a1.push *a2` work, but I'd like to talk about the last question you asked, on whether it's a good idea.

More specifically, if you are going to work with arrays that are millions of items long in production code, performance becomes something to keep in mind. http://www.continuousthinking.com/2011/09/07/ruby_array_plus_vs_push.html has an overview of 4 different ways to handle array concatenation in ruby: `+`, `.push`, `<<` and `.concat`.

There they mention that `array.push` will effectively handle each argument separately, and increase the array size by 50% every time the array is too small. This means that in your example, `a` will be increased in size 2 times and get 1 million appends. Meanwhile, `array.concat` will first calculate the new size of the array, extend the original array and then copy the new array into the right place.

For situations like yours, `concat` will most likely be more performant, both from a memory and from a CPU usage perspective. However, without benchmarks I can't say for sure. My recommendation is to measure the time and memory usage to do both operations for the size of the arrays you want to handle. `concat` will most likely come out on top, but I might be mistaken on that front.

Comment: A while ago I asked [How to efficiently concatenate multiple arrays in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40510579/477037) – the answers also have benchmarks.