# How to pass an array of strings and get an array of strings in Ruby using Go shared library?

Tags: ruby, go, ffi

I am trying to call a Go project from Ruby. It does work well when I pass a string and get back a string:

Go:

```
package main

import "C"
import (
    "fmt"

    "gitlab.com/gogna/gnparser"
)

//export ParseToJSON
func ParseToJSON(name *C.char) *C.char {
    goname := C.GoString(name)
    gnp := gnparser.NewGNparser()
    parsed, err := gnp.ParseAndFormat(goname)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return C.CString("")
    }
    return C.CString(parsed)
}

func main() {}
```

I compile it with

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o libgnparser.so main.go
```

Ruby:

```
require 'ffi'

# test
module GNparser
  extend FFI::Library
  if Gem.platforms[1].os == 'darwin'
      ffi_lib './clib/mac/libgnparser.so'
  else
      ffi_lib './clib/linux/libgnparser.so'
  end
  attach_function :ParseToJSON, [:string], :string
end

puts GNparser.ParseToJSON("Homo sapiens L.")
```

How can I pass a Ruby array of strings to Go and get back an array of strings for such an example? (There is a method in the Go project that can deal with such an array in parallel)

Comment: `['array', 'of', 'strings'].map {|e| GNparser.ParseToJSON(e) }`

Comment: @marmeladze in my case I want to send an ['array', 'of', 'strings'] to Go, where expensive algorithms will be parallelized

Comment: Have you seen this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389334/how-do-i-handle-ruby-arrays-in-ruby-ffi-gem?

Comment: @Marian13, thanks, the answer gives a few hints, but I still cannot put together the whole answer

Comment: When passing an array to a function in C (and therefore FFI) you are rally passing a _pointer_, and you usually will need some way of specifying the length (i.e. another parameter). Similarly you can’t really return an array. You would need to return a pointer and (usually) the length. Often this is done by passing in pointers to the function that the function will fill in. Related to this is memory management–who allocates the memory and who is responsible for freeing it.

Comment: Note the CGo documentation says “Go array types are not supported; use a C pointer”, presumably for these reasons. The answer here will probably depend on the actual function signature exported from Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that there are two different runtimes in the process, Ruby and Go, and neither of them like others poking about in their internals. So in order to make a call from Ruby to Go you have to first get the data out of Ruby, and then into Go, and then get the results out of Go and then into Ruby. In effect you will have to go from Ruby to Go via C, even though there is no actual C code.

Starting from the Go side, lets say the function you want to use has a signature like this:

```
func TheFunc(in []string) []string
```

You could just export this in your shared library, which would give a C signature of:

```
extern GoSlice TheFunc(GoSlice p0);
```

where `GoSlice` is

```
typedef struct { void *data; GoInt len; GoInt cap; } GoSlice;
```

Whilst this might work, this is giving direct access to Go data, especially the return value, so isn’t really safe.

A solution would be to provide a wrapper function, that accepts a pointer to an array of C strings (i.e. `**char`) and the length of the array. The function could then unpack this data and convert it to Go arrays (or slices) and pass it on to the real function that does the work. This wrapper function would also need a way to get the results. One way would be to pass in a pointer to a pointer to an array of strings (i.e. `***char`) and the function can allocate the array, populate it with the result strings, and write its address to where this pointer is pointing to.

This solution has the downside of allocating the memory in Go and relying on the calling code to free it.

This gets a little messy, but it would look like this:

```
// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"
import "unsafe"

//export CTheFunc
func CTheFunc(in **C.char, len C.int, out ***C.char) {

    inSlice := make([]string, int(len))

    // We need to do some pointer arithmetic.
    start := unsafe.Pointer(in)
    pointerSize := unsafe.Sizeof(in)

    for i := 0; i< int(len); i++ {
        // Copy each input string into a Go string and add it to the slice.
        pointer := (**C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(start) + uintptr(i)*pointerSize))
        inSlice[i] = C.GoString(*pointer)
    }

    // Call the real function.
    resultSlice := TheFunc(inSlice)

    // Allocate an array for the string pointers.
    outArray := (C.malloc(C.ulong(len) * C.ulong(pointerSize)))

    // Make the output variable point to this array.
    *out = (**C.char)(outArray)

    // Note this is assuming the input and output arrays are the same size.
    for i := 0; i< int(len); i++ {
        // Find where to store the address of the next string.
        pointer := (**C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(outArray) + uintptr(i)*pointerSize))
        // Copy each output string to a C string, and add it to the array.
        // C.CString uses malloc to allocate memory.
        *pointer = C.CString(resultSlice[i])
    }

}
```

This provides a C function with the following signature that we can access from Ruby using FFI.

```
extern void CDouble(char** p0, int p1, char*** p2);
```

The Ruby side of things is quite similar, but in reverse. We need to copy the data into a C array, and allocate some memory that we can pass the address of to receive the results, then pass the array, its length and the output pointer to the Go function. When it returns we need to copy the C data back into Ruby strings and arrays and free up the memory. It might look something like this:

```ruby
require 'ffi'

# We need this to be able to use free to tidy up.
class CLib
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib FFI::Library::LIBC
  attach_function :free, [:pointer], :void
end

class GoCaller
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib "myamazinggolibrary.so"
  POINTER_SIZE = FFI.type_size(:pointer)

  attach_function :CTheFunc, [:pointer, :int, :pointer], :void

  # Wrapper method that prepares the data and calls the Go function.
  def self.the_func(ary)
    # Allocate a buffer to hold the input pointers.
    in_ptr = FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:pointer, ary.length)
    # Copy the input strings to C strings, and write the pointers to in_ptr.
    in_ptr.write_array_of_pointer(ary.map {|s| FFI::MemoryPointer.from_string(s)})

    # Allocate some memory to receive the address of the output array.
    out_var = FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:pointer)

    # Call the actual function.
    CTheFunc(in_ptr, ary.length, out_var)

    # Follow the pointer in out_var, and convert to an array of Ruby strings.
    # This is the return value.
    out_var.read_pointer.get_array_of_string(0, ary.length)
  ensure
    # Free the memory allocated in the Go code. We don’t need to free
    # the memory in the MemoryPointers, it is done automatically.
    out_var.read_pointer.get_array_of_pointer(0, ary.length).each {|p| CLib.free(p)}
    CLib.free(out_var.read_pointer)
  end
end
```

This does involve copying the data twice in each direction, out of (or into) Ruby and then into (or out of) Go, but I don’t think it’s possible to do it any other way without the runtimes (especially the garbage collectors) tripping up over each other. It might be possible to store the data directly in some shared area and operate on it without copying using `FFI::Pointer`s in Ruby and `unsafe` in Go, but that would defeat the purpose of using these languages in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain this is the right way to do it, but in this solution, the argument to be passed around is json encoded in ruby then json decoded in go.

The solution is probably inefficient, but, it is safe.

I slightly changed the ruby program to

```rb
require 'ffi'
require 'json'

# test
module GNparser
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib './libgnparser.so'
  attach_function :ParseToJSON, [:string], :string
end

puts GNparser.ParseToJSON(["Homo","sapiens","L."].to_json)
```

And the go program to

```golang
package main

import "C"
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

// "gitlab.com/gogna/gnparser"

// ParseToJSON exports ParseToJSON
//export ParseToJSON
func ParseToJSON(name *C.char) *C.char {
    goname := C.GoString(name)
    dec := []string{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(goname), &dec)
    // gnp := gnparser.NewGNparser()
    // parsed, err := gnp.ParseAndFormat(goname)
    // if err != nil {
    //  fmt.Println(err)
    //  return C.CString("")
    // }
    goname = fmt.Sprint(len(dec))
    return C.CString(goname)
}

func main() {}
```

Take care to add the `// export comment`, otherwise the symbol is not exported and the ruby program can not access it.

```sh
[mh-cbon@Host-001 rubycgo] $ go build -buildmode=c-shared -o libgnparser.so main.go
[mh-cbon@Host-001 rubycgo] $ objdump -TC libgnparser.so | grep Parse
000000000012fb40 g    DF .text  0000000000000042  Base        ParseToJSON
000000000012f780 g    DF .text  0000000000000051  Base        _cgoexp_fcc5458c4ebb_ParseToJSON
[mh-cbon@Host-001 rubycgo] $ ruby main.rb 
3
[mh-cbon@Host-001 rubycgo] $ ll
total 3008
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mh-cbon mh-cbon    1639 17 nov.  13:12 libgnparser.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mh-cbon mh-cbon 3063856 17 nov.  13:12 libgnparser.so
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mh-cbon mh-cbon     504 17 nov.  13:12 main.go
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mh-cbon mh-cbon     219 17 nov.  13:03 main.rb
```

Comment: I thought about this workaround, but the returning JSON string in my case would be too large and unmarshalling it in Ruby would not be practical. So I still need to send an array of strings and get back an array of strings.

Comment: There is a big difference in unmarshalling 100 000 smallish JSON strings vs unmarshalling one huge JSON with 100 000 elements.

Comment: yup, but i dont see how to handle a pointer in ruby. other alternatives i can think of all requires some sort of marshalling, so they are not better. I would try to use the ruby c types (https://mvolkmann.github.io/NFJS/RubyCExtensions.pdf), RArray to pass pointers around.

Comment: have you checked for this on ffi side ? https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Examples#array-of-strings

Comment: Yes, what I do not understand yet is how to correctly connect Ruby array, FFI, conversion to Go slice, conversion from Go slice to FF and Ruby array

Comment: not sure either, but i think that if you are to copy data from the ruby array to the go slice, it would take quite some time to process, very much like encode/decode. So i think there should be a go api to access methods to the ruby array. to return the ruby array i guess you return an unsafe.Pointer and receive it in ffi using :pointer. something like this :s