# How to handle ruby arrays of structs in ruby ffi gem?

Tags: c, ruby, ffi

*This is in reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389334/how-do-i-handle-ruby-arrays-in-ruby-ffi-gem) but with structs instead.*

I want to use the ruby ffi gem to call a c function which has an array of structs and its length as input variables.

```c
struct MyStruct {
    char a;
    int b;
    float c;
    double d;
};

void my_function(struct MyStruct *arr, unsigned int num);
```

I have created the ruby binding as:

```rb
module MyModule
    extend FFI::Library
    ffi_lib FFI::Library::LIBC
    ffi_lib "my_c_lib"

    class MyStruct < FFI::Struct
      layout(
          :a, :char, 
          :b, :int, 
          :c, :float, 
          :d, :double
      )
    end

    attach_function :my_function, [ MyStruct.ptr, :uint ], :void
end
```

I will like to make a call in ruby code like:

```rb
MyModule.my_function([#<MyModule::MyStruct>, #<MyModule::MyStruct>, #<MyModule::MyStruct>], 3)
```

How do I go about this?

The closest I could get to solving this issue is:

```rb
# Make the assumption that `arr` is a ruby array populated with `MyStruct` instances
ptr = FFI::MemoryPointer.new(MyModule::MyStruct, arr.size)
arr.size.times do | i |
    ptr.put(MyModule::MyStruct, i, arr[i]) # ERROR in `put': unsupported type 'MyModule::MyStruct' (ArgumentError)
end
MyModule.my_function(ptr, arr.length)
```

I also replaced the forth line since the `put` function ask that the first argument be a type where `FFI::StructByValue` should be returning the type (based on the documentation), but another error appears:

```rb
    ptr.put(MyModule::MyStruct.by_value, i, arr[i]) # ERROR in `put': unsupported type '#<FFI::StructByValue:0x0123456789abcdef' (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: You probably want a wrapper function that takes in an array, then expands that to the correct call with the `.length` determined automatically.